# THREE.Euler().copy issue with revision 88 and 89

Tags: three.js

the following code does not seem to work with revision 88 and beyond:

```
function moveAndLookAt(dstpos, dstlookat, duration = 500) {
    TWEEN.removeAll();

    var origpos = new THREE.Vector3().copy(camera.position); // original position
    var origrot = new THREE.Euler().copy(camera.rotation); // original rotation

    camera.position.set(dstpos.x, dstpos.y, dstpos.z);
    camera.lookAt(dstlookat);
    var dstrot = new THREE.Euler().copy(camera.rotation)

    // reset original position and rotation
    camera.position.set(origpos.x, origpos.y, origpos.z);
    camera.rotation.set(origrot.x, origrot.y, origrot.z);

    // position
    new TWEEN.Tween(this.camera.position).to({
        x: dstpos.x,
        y: dstpos.y,
        z: dstpos.z
    }, duration).start();;

    // rotation (using slerp)
    let scope =  this;
    (function () {
        var qa = new THREE.Quaternion().copy(camera.quaternion); // src quaternion
        var qb = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(dstrot); // dst quaternion
        var qm = new THREE.Quaternion();

        var o = {t: 0};
        new TWEEN.Tween(o).to({t: 1}, duration).onUpdate(function () {
          THREE.Quaternion.slerp(qa, qb, qm, o.t);
          scope.camera.quaternion.set(qm.x, qm.y, qm.z, qm.w);
        }).start();
    }).call(this);
}
```

The target object seem to disappear and no errors. It looks like the dstrot = new THREE.Euler().copy(camera.rotation) value is returning NaN instead of numeric numbers. The code was from a previous post:

[Tween camera position while rotation with slerp -- THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091876/tween-camera-position-while-rotation-with-slerp-three-js)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, my dstlookat worked fine when I was passing {x:2,y:2,z:2} with previous versions but the latest version seem to require defined Vector3 values.

Solution:

var dstlookat = {x:2, y: 2, z: 2};

to:

dstlookat = new THREE.Vector3( 2, 2, 2 );